# Logging to website using python

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping

In this webpage: 
https://login.library.nyu.edu/login

I am trying to log in using the link for NYU using python, this is what I have tried:

```
import requests
url ='https://shibboleth.nyu.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO?execution=e1s1'
login_data = {
   'j_username': username,
   'j_password': password,
    }
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(login_data)
s.headers.update(headers)
resp = s.post(url, data=data)
```

but it doesn't work and it redirect me to this page:
https://shibboleth.nyu.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO?execution=e3s1

Would you please let me know where I am making mistake or if I have to choose another approach. Thanks for your help.

Comment: *Redirect*? Your `url` value is exactly `"https://shibboleth.nyu.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO?execution=e3s1"` ! There is no redirection- you request it directly

Comment: I made a mistake in the url in the question, I edited it. The correct url is https://shibboleth.nyu.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO?execution=e1s1 and still same thing happens.